# The 'username' argument is invalid. while connecting to SharePoint Online Manager

Tags: sharepoint

I am connecting to SharePoint Online Manager like this below:-

```
protected SharePointOnlineCredentials GetCredentials()
        {
            return new SharePointOnlineCredentials(this.UserName,
                    this.GetSecurePassword(this.Password));
        }
```

I get an error saying - The 'username' argument is invalid.

Below is the SharePoint Online Credentials Class:-

```
#region Assembly Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
// C:\SourceCode\PDS Portal\JLL.PDS\packages\Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM.16.1.4727.1200\lib\net45\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
#endregion

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Security;

namespace Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
{
    public sealed class SharePointOnlineCredentials : ICredentials
    {
        public SharePointOnlineCredentials(string username, SecureString password);

        public string UserName { get; }

        public event EventHandler<SharePointOnlineCredentialsWebRequestEventArgs> ExecutingWebRequest;

        public string GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url);
        public string GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url, bool alwaysThrowOnFailure);
        public NetworkCredential GetCredential(Uri uri, string authType);
    }
}
```

Below is the Stack Trace. Any ideas ?

```
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials..ctor(String username, SecureString password)
   at JLL.PDS.Data.SharePoint.SharePointOnlineManager.GetCredentials() in C:\SourceCode\PDS Portal\JLL.PDS\JLL.PDS.Data.SharePoint\SharePointOnlineManager.cs:line 71
   at JLL.PDS.Data.SharePoint.SharePointOnlineManager.GetClientContext(String siteUrl) in C:\SourceCode\PDS Portal\JLL.PDS\JLL.PDS.Data.SharePoint\SharePointOnlineManager.cs:line 57
   at JLL.PDS.Data.SharePoint.SharePointUserProfileManager.Initialize() in C:\SourceCode\PDS Portal\JLL.PDS\JLL.PDS.Data.SharePoint\SharePointUserProfileManager.cs:line 43
   at JLL.PDS.Data.SharePoint.SharePointUserProfileManager.GetProfileImageData(Profile profile) in C:\SourceCode\PDS Portal\JLL.PDS\JLL.PDS.Data.SharePoint\SharePointUserProfileManager.cs:line 70
   at JLL.PDS.Model.Services.ProfileSyncService.<SaveProfilesToTargetDataSource>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\SourceCode\PDS Portal\JLL.PDS\JLL.PDS.Model\Services\ProfileSyncService.cs:line 106
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the username setting App.Config needed to be appended with the domain email. For example App Setting was XYZ, I had to make XYZ@abc.com. Not my fault as that was present in App.Config incorrectly. So whenever we get this error 'The 'username' argument is invalid.' that means we are sending the username incorrectly.

Comment: domain user is important if you trace decompiled source you saw there was a condition that checks find @ domain sign or not! we can't use username NetBios Format (Domain\user)